# proper name for custom User and Manager in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, naming-conventions, django-users

In my django project I've created a customized models for User and its manager class.
I named them **User** (which inherits from `AbstractUser`) and **UserManager** (which inherits from `BaseUserManager`). Given that these are the default django's name for those models, is there any problem in that?
I run the following form django shell:

```
>>>from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>>user = get_user_model() 
>>>user.objects
```

These are the outputs:

```
<class 'myapp.models.models.User'>
<class 'myapp.models.models.UserManager'>
```

Apparently no conflicts are shown, so it seems to be all right. I hope some django experts could confirm me I won't have any surprise later on through the development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with that.

However, you have to tell Django that you've done a custom User model and want to use it by defining the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting in your `settings.py` file.

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<name_of_your_app>.<name_of_your_user_model'`

In a project of mine, I did : `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.User'` for instance.

More info in official documentation [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: Yes, I've already specified it into **settings.py** thank you